# Jquery Datatables filtro pro frase completa

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable

Estou utilizando o datatables do Jquery, sempre utilizo ele, mais hoje estou com uma situação que não encontrei na documentação dele.
E o seguinte, quando a consulta e feita ele me traz o valor de diversos campos comparando por palavras, preciso que a busca seja feita pela frase completa em todas as colunas e não comparando palavra por palavra de todas as colunas.

Comment: Se você escrever a frase no filtro ele faz isso automaticamente

Comment: Sim amigo, mais ele pega as palavras em varias colunas. Ele não consulta pela frase inteira.

Comment: Você pode colocar a frase entre aspas duplas, assim ele busca a frase exata.

Comment: @RenatoDiniz Matou a charada amigo. E consigo travar isso para sem aspas?

Comment: Com as aspas funcionou, Tenho um banco onde preciso filtrar na coluna descrição e com outras colunas de status. Onde eles se misturavam. O banco e grande, e mesmo assim so acontece em algumas situações.

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro adicionei uma resposta explicando como fazer isso sem precisar das aspas.

Comment: Demorei pra entender sua necessidade, mas ai pesquisei mais afundo e achei na documentação

Comment: Fucei na documentação uns 30 min kkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**search.smart** possibilita a ativação e inativação do filtro inteligente

**Filtro inteligente**:

Quebra a entrada do usuário em palavras individuais e, em seguida, corresponde a essas palavras em qualquer posição e em qualquer ordem na tabela (em vez de simples fazer uma comparação de string simples).

https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.smart

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "search": {
    "smart": false
  }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Amigo, e você sabe me dizer se da pra inverter o nome search com o campo de busca? Sabe, o search ta do lado esquerdo, e o input ta do lado direito. Queria inverter eles.

Comment: na verdade basta você acessar o dataTables, foi de lá que ele retirou esse código de exemplo, e assim terá todo esclarecimento

Answer (score 2):

Você pode buscar colocando o texto entre aspas duplas ou desabilitar a função Smart Search do DataTable, adicionando essa configuração ao iniciar a tabela:

```
$('#tabela').dataTable({
  "search": {
    "smart": false
  }
});
```